# how to avoid repeating pattern when creating form in react

Tags: reactjs

I am going to update the form with each keystroke with useState Hook this way I have to add an onChange event listener plus a function for each input and as you can imagine it's going to be lots of functions how can I avoid repeating myself?

```
function  firstNamInput(){
    
}
function  lastNameInput(){
    
}
function  emailInput(){
    
}
function  phoneInput(){
    
}
function  addressInput(){
    
}
function  genderInput(){
    
}
function  jobInput(){
    
}
function  ageInput(){
    
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in react we try to collect form data on every keystroke but in the past, we used to collect form data when submit clicked. so because of this new approach, we have to listen for every keystroke on every input!  isn't this crazy? yes, kind of but there is a way to go around I am going to explain it to you :
first I am going to talk about Rules you have to know about inputs:

1. we are  going to use a useState Hook and we pass an object to it which contain:

   - a property for every input that's single
   - a property for group inputs (for example if there is checkboxes for gender we create only one property for gender)
2. what attributes every input should have?

   - name (it's going to be equal to its property in the useState)
   - value or checked (as a rule of thumb if the inputs gets true or false its usually checked vice versa )
   - onChange event
     so let's create useState I am going to have a total of 7 properties in the object:

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {
            firstName: "", 
            lastName: "", 
            email: "", 
            comments: "", 
            isFriendly: true,
            employment: "",
            favColor: ""
        }
    )
```

we need to create a  function for the onChange event i am going to make it as reusable as possible it's going to get form data from each input and update it in our Hook.

```
function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
            }
        })
    }
```

now we are going to add inputs look at note 2 again and now you are ready

```
import React from "react"

export default function Form() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {
            firstName: "", 
            lastName: "", 
            email: "", 
            comments: "", 
            isFriendly: true,
            employment: "",
            favColor: ""
        }
    )
    
    function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
            }
        })
    }
    
    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        // submitToApi(formData)
        console.log(formData)
    }
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="firstName"
                value={formData.firstName}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="lastName"
                value={formData.lastName}
            />
            <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="email"
                value={formData.email}
            />
            <textarea 
                value={formData.comments}
                placeholder="Comments"
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="comments"
            />
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                id="isFriendly" 
                checked={formData.isFriendly}
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="isFriendly"
            />
            <label htmlFor="isFriendly">Are you friendly?</label>
            <br />
            <br />
            
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Current employment status</legend>
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="unemployed"
                    name="employment"
                    value="unemployed"
                    checked={formData.employment === "unemployed"}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="unemployed">Unemployed</label>
                <br />
                
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="part-time"
                    name="employment"
                    value="part-time"
                    checked={formData.employment === "part-time"}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="part-time">Part-time</label>
                <br />
                
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id="full-time"
                    name="employment"
                    value="full-time"
                    checked={formData.employment === "full-time"}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="full-time">Full-time</label>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            
            <label htmlFor="favColor">What is your favorite color?</label>
            <br />
            <select 
                id="favColor" 
                value={formData.favColor}
                onChange={handleChange}
                name="favColor"
            >
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="orange">Orange</option>
                <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
                <option value="violet">Violet</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```